# Rewrite url without affecting the server request method

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This is my question:
I want to remove the ".php" extension from my URL.
I found this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

... which works, but I have a problem.
I don't really know why, but this code somehow changes the server request method from
POST to GET. So if I use this code in my .htaccess file, I can't use the POST method anymore.
So.. Is there any other way to hide the ".php" extension?
Thank you anyways :)

Comment: the `[R]` flag will do that for you. What you can do is (1) don't redirect on a `%{REQUEST_METHOD} POST` while you're working, (2) alter all your forms action attributes to the _new_ desired URL to also have nice POSTs. Rewriting is all and well, but one should _also_ fix the links, which includes form actions.

Comment: I don't really know how to do it :(

Comment: Wait, what, you don't know how to alter the form action attributes in your HTML? Seriously? Is some framework you're using getting in the way or something?

Comment: .. I kinda just started

Comment: Well, [here's your start](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp), those things need to go to urls without the `.php`.

Comment: I can't use the GET method. I need the POST one. I need to upload a file...

Comment: That is _totally_ beside the point I'm trying to make. An action attribute is NOT the same as a method attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works this way because you are `[R]`edirecting all requests ending in .php to a new URL without .php. You are doing a redirect. You cannot redirect POST requests. If you don't want the .php at the end, don't link to those URLs. Make your form action submit to the non-.php URL directly.